# Missing tabs from Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, rest, web

I needing to debug an asp.net/json web services for a project I'm working on that is not working, and need to use Chrome Developer tools.

When I bring up developer tools, the only panel button I have is the Elements panel, and it is grayed out.  I do not have the Resources, Network, Scripts, Timeline, Profile, Audits, or Console panel buttons.

I have Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m.  Due to the problem I'm having, I also installed [Chrome 28.0.1486.0 canary](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html).  When I first installed canary, the panel buttons were there, then they disappeared.

I have searched for a solution, but have not found anything that would explain why I am missing this functionality.

I have the following extensions installed:

- Advanced REST Client  3.1.2
- Clearly 9.3366.554.201
- Google Docs .5
- HTML Validator 1.3.3
- RSS Subscription Extension (by Google) 2.2.2
- Speed Tracer (by Google) 0.27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, quite by accident.  The buttons were there, but the theme I was using made them appear white-on-white.  I changed the theme and now they are visible.  The icon graphic is not displayed, though.